# Decidability Turing Machine Problem

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar, turing-machines

> $L=\{G|G$ is a context free grammar over ${a,b}$ and $L\{G\}$ contains
>   at least one string $w$ such that the number of $a$'s in $w$ is a
>   multiple of $5\}$
>
> Show that L is decidable by giving a high level description of a
>   turing machine.

I understand the proof of how to do this given a CFG and string w and deciding whether w is a part of the CFG using a TM, but I'm not entirely sure how to approach the extra constraint.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Outline.** Possibly not the smoothest solution, but one way to go about this to note that the language $$L_{\mathtt{5a}} = \{ w \in \{ \mathtt{a} , \mathtt{b} \}^* : \text{the number of }\mathtt{a}\text{s in }w\text{ is a multiple of }5 \}$$ is regular, and that the intersection of a regular language and a context-free language is context-free.  (Since a DFA uses no storage memory you can run a DFA and a PDA "in parallel".)  An algorithm would then be to construct a CFG/PDA for $L_{\mathtt{5a}} \cap L(G)$ and then check whether the language of this CFG/PDA is nonempty.

Comment: Wow thanks I didn't think of that.